# How to delay for 5 sec and then use file_get_contents PHP?

Tags: php

How to delay for 5 sec and then use `file_get_contents` PHP ?

I use this code for get text from webpage using url.

index.php

```
<?PHP
$text = file_get_contents('https://www.othersite.com/test_1.php');
echo strip_tags($text); // If you only need text not html structure
?>
```

.

.

https://www.othersite.com/test_1.php

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=https://www.othersite.com/test_2.php">
```

https://www.othersite.com/test_2.php

```
HELLO WORLD.
```

When i load mysite (index.php). how to delay for 5 sec then use `file_get_contents` and it's will show result `HELLO WORLD.`

Comment: What's the delay for?

Comment: ok if not delay when i use `file_get_contents` with `test_1.php` it's will show blank data. i want to delay for 5 sec for redirect to `test_2.php` before use `file_get_contents` and result will be `HELLO WORLD.`

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: None of the answers really solve OP's issues. I think OP wants to delay some seconds until the page is fully loaded, especially the contents being loaded by JS. To do so, you can make use of PhantomJS or CasperJS to achieve this (not PHP, though).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP function [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Example:

```
<?PHP
sleep(5); //Sleeps for 5 sec
$text = file_get_contents('https://www.othersite.com/test_1.php');
echo strip_tags($text); // If you only need text not html structure
?>
```

Comment: well... yeah, that's what OP asked. But I don't think that he wants to do that. Just another XY problem

Comment: @Federkun What do you think he wants to do?

Comment: I've no idea. That's what you should ask him

Comment: ok if not delay when i use `file_get_contents` with `test_1.php` it's will show blank data. i want to delay for 5 sec for redirect to `test_2.php` before use `file_get_contents` and result will be `HELLO WORLD.`

Comment: @kamongkamong So you want to echo the content of `strip_tags($text)` AND after that you want to redirect a user to a page?

Comment: no, when i use this code, `<?PHP
$text = file_get_contents('https://www.othersite.com/test_1.php');
echo strip_tags($text); // If you only need text not html structure
?>` result will be blank, are you ok ?

Comment: Can you try `var_dump(trip_tags($text));` and give me the output?

Comment: Have you turned on error reporing? This looks like a hidden error message or something like that
`ini_set('display_errors,'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
sleep(5); // seconds
```

function

Comment: perhaps the sleep(5); should go after the file_get_contents to give it time to load?